# Insert values to the oracle table using python cx_oracle Session Pool

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g, python-3.8, cx-oracle

Can any one help how to insert a single row into the oracle table using the python cx_oracle Session Pool? I am seeing some issue with the below code.

> ```sql
> Type error: expecting string or object
> Name Null? Type        
> ---- ----- ------------
> ID         NUMBER(38)  
> NAME       VARCHAR2(30)
> ```

```py
def connections():
    pool = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(user='system',password='oracle',dsn='localhost/orcl', min=5, max=5)
    connection = pool.acquire()
    cur = connection.cursor()

    return cur


def update_table(cursor):
    rows=[(2,"KRR")]
    sql=("insert into exm(id,name) values(:1, :2)", rows)
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: where do you invoke `update_table`?

Comment: you can replace `"KRR"` with `'KRR'` as the whole statement is wrapped already in the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two problems with your code.

The first is that you are not calling `cursor.execute` correctly. You are creating a tuple in the line

```py
    sql=("insert into exm(id,name) values(:1, :2)", rows)
```

which you then pass to

```py
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

This has the same effect of running the following line (note the extra parentheses):

```py
   cursor.execute(("insert into exm(id,name) values(:1, :2)", rows))
```

when you really want to run this line, which doesn't have the extra parentheses:

```py
   cursor.execute("insert into exm(id,name) values(:1, :2)", rows)
```

I would recommend that you instead set `sql` to just the SQL string to run against the database, and pass `rows` to `cursor.execute` separately.

```py
    sql="insert into exm(id,name) values(:1, :2)"
    cursor.execute(sql, rows)
```

The second problem is that you seem to want to insert multiple rows at the same time. You hint at this by naming your variable `rows` and assigning a 1-element list of tuples to it. To insert multiple rows at the same time, you need to use `cursor.executemany`, not `cursor.execute`:

```py
    sql="insert into exm(id,name) values(:1, :2)"
    cursor.executemany(sql, rows)
```

Comment: A reference on `executemany()` is the user doc https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html